# program close when open csv file in qtable

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

when I added function for a button to show data in `CSV` file when I click the program, it closes itself. I altered my code, however, the same problem persists.

Debug does not show any error messages. I'm a beginner in `qt` and if there alternatives to `qtablewidget` or better ways to tackle this, please let me know.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'officer.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.6
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

import sys
import csv
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):
def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName("Form")
    Form.resize(930, 650)
    self.fname = "data.csv"
    self.combo_data2 = {0: ['إيهاب السيد محمود السيد'],
                        1: ['محمد مدحت محمد', 'محمد عبدالرؤوف متولي', 'وليد عزت عبدالمؤمن', 'هاني حسنين أحمد حسنين',
                            'محمود السيد سليمان'], 2: ['حازم فتحي مختار', 'أمير محمود سيد', 'أحمد عبدالجليل'],
                        3: ['ابراهيم مختار عبدالقوي', "أحمد عفيفي محمود عفيفي", 'محمود عبدالعزيز عبدالحميد',
                            'حسام جابر عبدالعزيز', 'إسلام مصطفى محمد', 'محمد عطيوة عبدالرازق'],
                        4: ["إسلام عبدالرحمن حسن", "محمد عبدالمنعم محمد يونس", 'محمد فتحي عبدالوهاب',
                            'محمود عبدالسلام', 'عاصم عادل عبدالعزيز'],
                        5: ["أحمد محمد عزت", "محمد رضا عبدالعظيم", "أحمد رمضان موسى", "عمر عناني عناني",
                            "حازم سامي ابراهيم", 'عبدالرحمن سمير ', 'أحمد محمد ابراهيم', 'محمد أحمد عايش',
                            'سعيد مدحت رأفت', 'أحمد محمد محمود البقري', 'وليد ابراهيم عبدالمجيد',
                            'محمد عبدالحميد سالم', 'حاتم محمد نجيب'], 6: ["محمود سامي عبدالغفار شعير"]}
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 60, 75, 22))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.pushButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
    self.pushButton1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 110, 85, 22))
    self.pushButton1.setObjectName("pushButton1")
    self.pushButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
    self.pushButton2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 110, 85, 22))
    self.pushButton2.setObjectName("pushButton2")
    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Form)
    self.tableWidget.setEnabled(True)
    self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)  # Make table not editable
    self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 151, 881, 471))
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(38)
    self.col_headers = ['الرتبة', 'الإسم', 'رصيد سنوية', 'رصيد عارضة']
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.col_headers)
    self.tableWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
    header = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
    header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    header.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
    self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(728, 60, 121, 22))
    self.comboBox.setEditable(False)
    self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox.addItem("")
    self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
    self.comboBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
    self.comboBox_2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
    self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect( 348, 60, 311, 22))
    self.comboBox_2.setEditable(False)
    self.comboBox_2.setCurrentText("")
    self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
    self.tableWidget.raise_()
    self.pushButton.raise_()
    self.comboBox.raise_()
    self.comboBox_2.raise_()
    self.set_combo()
    self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.set_combo)
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_csv)
    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

def open_csv(self):
    with open(self.fname , 'r') as record :
        for row_data in csv.reader(record):
            row = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
            for col , data in enumerate(row_data):
                item = QtGui.QTextTableCellFormat(data)
                self.tableWidget.setItem( row , col, item)

def search(self):
    print 'search'

def set_combo(self):
    self.comboBox_2.clear()
    x = self.comboBox.currentIndex()
    self.comboBox_2.addItems(self.combo_data2[x])
    print x
    print type(x)

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "بيانات الضباط"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "بحث"))
    self.pushButton1.setText(_translate("Form", "خصم عارضة"))
    self.pushButton2.setText(_translate("Form", "خصم سنوية"))
    self.comboBox.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>الرتبة</p></body></html>"))
    self.comboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("Form", "الرتبة"))
    self.comboBox_2.setCurrentText(_translate("Form", "الإسم"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "عميد"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "عقيد"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "مقدم"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Form", "رائد"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("Form", "نقيب"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("Form", "ملازم أول"))
    self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("Form", "ملازم"))
    self.comboBox_2.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p>الإسم</p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand why you use `QTextTableCellFormat`, `QTableWidget` expects a `QTableWidgetItem`:

```
def open_csv(self):
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    with open(self.fname , 'r') as record :
        for row_data in csv.reader(record):
            row = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
            for col , data in enumerate(row_data):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data)
                self.tableWidget.setItem( row , col, item)
```

Comment: I tied it before same problem

Comment: @MahmoudShoair Is the application still closing? Test returned my updated solution